# Does running the tree command make subsequent commands faster?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, speed

Just wanted to clear something out:
I noticed that if I run the `tree` command before any other commands (read/write/modify/transfer/copy/compare), they actually seem to execute faster.

A reason for this may be that that if you run the tree command, cmd already knows where a specific directory is located...

I have not timed anything, but maybe the difference would be more noticeable on an older, slower PC?

Then again, maybe I just need more sleep... :/

Comment: Does NO ONE have an answer?? :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that `cmd.exe` or the `tree` program "remember" where a file/directory is, it's that Windows (the lower level disk/IO drivers) or the physical disk itself might put that file table info (or the file(s) themselves) in a cache that makes it slightly faster to access it on the next go round, so when you run a command (like `del` or `copy`) or even go to open the file in something like Media Player or Notepad, Windows and the disk don't have to do as much work to access the specific location being requested.

This isn't necessarily true for all types of disks though, like a USB/SSD drive or a mapped network drive, which work very differently than a spinning disk drive; that is to say that running `C:> tree` and then running `notepad "C:\some\file.txt"` might see you have the file open slightly faster due to the way the disk access works getting to `file.txt` on the phsyical disk *vs.* if you ran `X:> tree` (where `X` is a mapped network drive) and then did `notepad "X:\some\file.txt"`, you'd probably see `file.txt` get accessed at the same "speed" regardless (since it's over the network).

So to answer your question more directly:

> Does running the tree command make subsequent commands faster?

It can depend on certain factors (like disk type for example) and results may vary, but if there's a caching mechanism in place, then there's a good chance that subsequent access to a file can be faster.

Hope that can help.